# Science fiction story. Planet becomes 'malleable' and starts to roll up and down. Inhabitants have hollow legs

Tags: story-identification

I read this in 1984.  It was a somewhat goofy story about a planet of people with hollow legs.  Now and then the surface of the planet would become malleable and roll up & down.

By no means do I think it was any kind of serious epic story - I'd just like to read it again.

Any ideas out there?  Maybe my being on a Costa Rican beach tagging Green Sea Turtles at night as the skies burst with lightning had something to do with why I liked the book - someone left this little paperback at the research station, so I read it by candlelight.

Comment: Is the research station still there?

Comment: @Valorum I seriously doubt that the OP could phone them up and ask if the book is still lying around.

Comment: @MrLister - Why not? Or at the very least there might be someone who worked there that also read it...

Comment: @Valorum After 33 years? Oh well.

Comment: @MrLister - I heard a rumour that archeologists have discovered some books that are old than 33 years.

Comment: A new station is there, the old one likely was eaten by termites as well as everything in it!  They are still tagging sea turtles, too.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly 'The Lavalite World' Phillip Jose Farmer. I don't remember the hollow legs but the surface rolling up and down rings a bell. Not his best work.